# Error using yum in centos 6

Tags: linux, centos

my yum command used to work fine , but now , when I try to use it ,

it gives me an error :

```
file:///home/user/repo/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14]
 Could not open/read file:///home/user/repo/repodata/repomd.xml
```

I don't know what to do , please help me.

Comment: Please post  the result of `ls -l /home/user/repo/repodata/repomd.xml`

Comment: Maybe this question should be migrated to [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: there is no user  folder in my /home @Atropo

Comment: @AlirezaFallah change `user` with your `username`

Comment: @Atropo I did , there is also no repo directory under my /home/alireza/ directory

Answer (score 0):

If `user` is to be replaced with your username on the system a fix for this is to edit the file

```
/home/user/repo/repodata/repomd.xml
```

Look for:

```
enabled=1
```

and change it to

```
enabled=0
```

After that do a `yum update` and it should work fine.

Comment: there is NO such directory in my system , thats my problem